# In Datomic, querying field history with no retractions?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'd like to get the history of values for a particular field in Datomic.
My intuition is to use `(d/history)` like

```clj
(d/q '[:find ?entity ?field-val ?date ?tx
       :in $
       :where 
          [?entity :namespace/field ?field-val ?tx]
          [?tx :db/txInstant ?date]]
      (d/history (db/get-db)))
```

However, this query will duplicate most values because it lists every retraction as well as every value update (every `db/add` and `db/retract`).

I thought maybe I could query the datoms with the transaction, then check the operations. But I can't find a way to query the datoms.

- `(d/pull db '[*] tx-id)` doesn't include datoms.
- search engine results were not helpful for keywords like "query datomic transaction datoms"
- searching for datomic transaction schema is not fruitful

I can use `tx-range`, but that seems unweildly.

Any better approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong place. History queries offer an extra hidden positional value described in the [history docs](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/tutorial/history.html#history-query).

So any where clause can include `?entity ?attribute ?value ?transaction ?operation`.

- ?operation is true for `:db/add` and false for `:db/retract`

So, the query I want looks like

```clj
(d/q '[:find ?entity ?field-val ?date ?tx
       :in $
       :where 
          [?entity :namespace/field ?field-val ?tx true] ;;ADDED TRUE
          [?tx :db/txInstant ?date]]
      (d/history (db/get-db)))
```